# Cropping Pandas dataframe saving age/sex distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe (base) containing people.

[image]

I dont need so many entries in my dataframe and would like to reduce it to about 10k people saving the age/sex distribution.

I have an approach using loop. Run over each age, counting len(base[(base["age"] == AGE & (base["sex"] == SEX)]), cropping and then concating resulting dataframes. But I think there should be better approach.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: You want a `sample` of the dataframe. Try `base.sample(10000)` Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Comment: Hm, well probably that really is a solution. I check the percantage, it ruins a bit distributon inside some ages, however I dont think it is very critical. Thank you)
However if somebody has not such random-dependent solution, it would be pleased anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby_sample` to preserve distribution:

```
out = df.groupby(['sex', 'age']).sample(frac=0.1)
```

Output:

```
>>> len(df)
100000

>>> len(out)
9999
```

```
>>> df.value_counts(['sex', 'age'], normalize=True).sort_index()
sex  age
0    0      0.00472
     1      0.00538
     2      0.00518
     3      0.00512
     4      0.00521
             ...   
1    95     0.00508
     96     0.00506
     97     0.00503
     98     0.00490
     99     0.00509
Length: 200, dtype: float64

>>> out.value_counts(['sex', 'age'], normalize=True).sort_index()
sex  age
0    0      0.004700
     1      0.005401
     2      0.005201
     3      0.005101
     4      0.005201
              ...   
1    95     0.005101
     96     0.005101
     97     0.005001
     98     0.004900
     99     0.005101
Length: 200, dtype: float64
```

Distribution:

[image]